# Add attribute to <tr> from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a jQuery takes the value from the between the  tags to be an attribute named data-row-key="xx"

my html looks like this:

```html
<table id="linksgrid">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grid-row">
      <td class="grid-cell" data-name="BrokenLink_ID">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grid-row">
      <td class="grid-cell" data-name="BrokenLink_ID">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but I need to look like this:

```html
<table id="Table1">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grid-row" data-row-key="1">
      <td class="grid-cell" data-name="BrokenLink_ID">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grid-row" data-row-key="2">
      <td class="grid-cell" data-name="BrokenLink_ID">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

noticed the added attribute to the  tag,

any help or hint to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated, thanks

**UPDATE**
before I posted the question i tried

```js
$('td[data-name="BrokenLink_ID"]').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).text();

  var table = document.getElementById('linksgrid');
  var rows = table.rows;
  for (var i = 0, 1 = rows.lenght; i < l; i++) {
    rows[i].data = id
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#linksgrid tr').each(function() {
   $(this).data('row-key', $(this).text());
   // or $(this).attr('data-row-key', $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grid-cell').each(function(){ // loop through each grid-cell
    var currentValue = $(this).text(); // get its text
    $(this).closest('.grid-row').attr('data-row-key', currentValue); // add the attribute to the grid-cell's parent
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.grid-cell').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('data-row-key', $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// run a function on each instance of .grid-row
$('.grid-row').each(function() {

    // grab the text from the current child .grid-cell
    var myAttrVal = $(this).find('.grid-cell').text();

    // add the attribute to this row
    $(this).attr('data-row-key', myAttrVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all `tr` elements and add a `data-row-key` value as follows:

```
$('#linksgrid tbody tr').data('row-key', function() {
    return $('td', this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grid-row').each(function() {
    var no = $(this).children('td').text() 
    $(this).attr('data-row-key', no);
});
```